# While loop in Python converting integer to a string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, while-loop, integer

So I can't seem to get this. Without the 'while' loop this code works fine but as soon as I apply the loop it stops working right. From some reason it's treating x as a string. Like if x were 2 it would print y as '2222' instead of 16. I'm still new at this can someone tell my why? Thanks!

```
go = 'y'

while go == 'y':

    print('enter x')
    x = input()

    y = x * 4

    print(y)
print('go again?')

go = input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3's `input` function always returns a string. This is a change from Python 2, where `input` returned different kinds of Python objects depending on what was entered by the user. Python 3's version is equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input`.

With that background in mind, it's easy to fix your code. Just call the `int` constructor to turn your string into an integer. Or if you want to support non-integer values (like `1.4`), use `float` instead.

As an aside, as your code is currently formatted in the question, it has an infinate loop. Is your logic to change the `go` variable really at top level? If so, it won't ever change during the loop, which will run forever.

Comment: Thanks Blckknight! I got it now I just used 'x = int(input())'. And I saw the go thing lol. I just don't get why that same code worked outside the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

This is actually dependent on your python version.  `input` will automatically convert your string to an integer if it finds one.  To prevent this, use the `raw_input` function in python < 3.  For python 3 and above I believe this is the default behavior.